# Make CSS animation stop after it leaves visible screen

Tags: css, css-animations

Using css animation I have an object that moves from the left to the right of the screen. However I've noticed that the animation is actually continuing after it has exited the right of the screen, which causes Chrome horizontal scroll bars to appear.

If you scroll right, it just shows the animated object no longer moving and a white background screen.

How do I kill the animation as soon as it leaves the view able screen?

The actual animation can be seen here. http://crea8tion.com/ChristmasMessage/index.html

The CSS code for the object is

```
.santa {
    width: 1000px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -14%;
    left: -55%;
    -webkit-animation: santa-move 1s 1s ease-out forwards;
    -webkit-animation-delay:5s;animation-delay:5s;                   
    -webkit-animation-duration: 25s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes santa-move {
    100% { left: 100%;}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simple way to remove this extra scrollbar.

You can add a simple overlay: hidden to the parent div. In your case:

```
.columns {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

In this case, the santa animation didn't anymore add the horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: Hi, actually that did'nt seem to work. I updated the code on the above link to show that the horizontal scrollbar still appears

Comment: Have you tried to insert the overflow: hidden to the div above `.large-12` or `.columns` ?